# Param is missing or the value is empty don't take parameters, just id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a relation has_and_belongs_to_many with places and events. When i create a event dont save the places parameters but yes the others parameters. However, when i want to edit a event, this dont take the paremeters saved. (image) ¿what is the problem with the parameters and why dont save the ralation? Thanks

Event Model

```html
cla
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sponsors 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :places
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :places
    
end
```

Place Model

```html
 has_and_belongs_to_many :events  
  has_one :scores 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categorys 
 
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
```

Events Controller

```html
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  
  before_action :events_params, only: [:create, :edit]




  def index
   @event = Event.all
  end

 def show
    @event = Event.find(get_event)

  end

  def new 
   @event = Event.new
  end

def create
    @event = Event.new(events_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to events_path, notice: "Almacenado"
    else
      render "new", notice: "Danm"
    end
  end

def edit
    params_filtered = Event.find(events_params)
    @event = Event.find(get_event)
    if @event.update(params_filtered)
      redirect_to events_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(get_event)
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to events_path
  end

  private
  def events_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:website,:city,:whybuy,:moendreinfo,:title,:description, :datestart, :dateend, :hourstart, :hourend, :price ,:avatar, :background, places_atributtes: []) 
  end

 def get_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end




end
```

Routes

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :places do
  resources :events
  end 

 resources :events
 get "events/:id" => "events#show"
 get "events/:id/edit" => "events#edit"
  
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  devise_scope :users do
  get "profile_user/:id" => "users_profiles#profile_user"
  get "usersall" => "users_profiles#usersall"
  end

end
```

Link of bug error

i.stack.imgur.com/Snl2m.png

Form Event new

```html
<html>
<head>
 
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body id="newevent">
   <h3> Crear Evento </h3>
    <div  class="container-fluid">
        <div  class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12  ">

           
              <di>
                    <div id="divnewevent" >

                        <%=form_for @event do |eve|%>
                         <%= eve.label :title, "Titulo del evento" %></br>
                          <%= eve.text_field :title,  class:"form-control", placeholder:"Stingi Fest Back Color", autofocus: true%></br>
                         <%= eve.label :description, "Descripción" %></br>
                         <%= eve.text_field :description,  class:"form-control", placeholder:"No debe superar los 140 caracteres", autofocus: true%></br>
                         
                          <%= eve.collection_select(:place_ids, Place.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {multiple: true, class: "input-lg"}) %>
                          
                          <%= eve.label :datestart, "Fecha de apertura" %></br>
                          <%= eve.date_select :datestart, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Fecha de apertura o día del evento", autofocus: true %></br>

                         <%= eve.label :dateend, "Fecha de cierre" %></br>
                         <%= eve.date_select :dateend,  class:"form-control", placeholder:"Fecha de cierre o día del evento", autofocus: true %></br>
                         <%= eve.label :hourstart, "Hora inicio" %></br>
                         <%= eve.time_select :hourstart,  class:"form-control", placeholder:"Hora de inicio", autofocus: true %> </br>
                         
                         <%= eve.label :hourend, "Hora cierre" %></br>
                         <%= eve.time_select :hourend, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Hora de cierre", autofocus: true %></br>

                          <%= eve.label :website, "website" %></br>
                          <%= eve.text_field :website, class:"form-control", placeholder:"www.cosito.com", autofocus: true  %></br>

                          <%= eve.label :city, "ciudad" %></br>
                          <%= eve.text_field :city, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Ciudad,co", autofocus: true %></br>

                          <%= eve.label :price, "Costo" %>
                          <%= eve.text_field :price, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Costo de entrada", autofocus: true %> </br>
                       
                          
                          <%= eve.label :whybuy, "Por qué asistir o comprar y dónde" %></br>
                          <%= eve.text_field :whybuy, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Plus de insentivo y donde comprar", autofocus: true %></br>
                          <%= eve.label :moreinfo, "más info" %></br>
                          <%= eve.text_field :moreinfo, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Mayor información", autofocus: true %></br>
                          <%= eve.label :avatar, "Foto de perfil" %>
                           <%= eve.file_field :avatar %>
                           <%= eve.label :background, "Foto de fondo" %>
                           <%= eve.file_field :background %>



                          <%= eve.submit %>
                         <%end%>

                            </div>                  
                   </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have too low rep to comment.

Please show the view of the form . It appears as if the parameters doesn't live up to your

```
params.require(:event)
```

Edit:

I think you do not use your `event_params` the right way, you should call this function only when you want to check the given parameters and look for your permitted attributes.

You should remove the

```
before_action :event_params
```

But add:

```
before_action :get_event, except: [:new, :index, :create]
```

This will make sure that you will set the current event in the @event-variable before `show, update, destroy`.

I think your culprit could be that you do not have an `update`-method, you appear do this in your `edit`-method as well.

`edit` is the action that loads the page where you can edit your event.
`update`is the action that you send to from your form. This is where you will use `@event.update(...)`.

**So your `edit` and `update` can look like:**

```
def edit
end

def update
  if @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was updated'
  else
    render action: :edit
  end
end
```

(If you added the `before_action :get_event`).